# First visible td and last visible td in css

Tags: css

I am trying to style first and last visible td inside tr.
I can acheive above with peice of jquery, but in my case need to handle many scenarios and testing will take time.

After lot of research, i could not get anything in css.

Is there any other simple hack or work around so that i can acheive only with css.

Below are few options, which i tried

```css
.visible {
display : block;
}

.hidden {
display : none;
}

td:first-child {
}

td:last-child {
}

td.visible:first-child {
}

td.visible:last-child {
}
```

Comment: The appropriate CSS selector is dependent on the HTML, which you haven't yet shown; please: remember to share your [mcve].

Comment: Your code is working ... don't know where you are stuck

Comment: @DavidJorHpan my code will wprk perfectly only if all the td are visible. if i hide last column, style should get applied to the visible last column

Answer (score 3):

> There is not in css move to backward,so we can't select `td` with class `cant` with pure css.

```css
.hidden  {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.cant {
  background-color: orange!important;
}

tr td.hidden + td:not(.hidden) , tr td:not(.hidden):first-child { 
  background-color: red;
}

tr td.hidden + td:not(.hidden) ~ td , tr td:not(.hidden):first-child ~ td { 
  background-color: unset;
}

tr td:not(.hidden):last-child,tr td:not(.hidden):last-child {
  background-color: red!important;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td class="hidden">This is TR1_TD1</td>
    <td>This is TR1_TD2</td>
    <td class="hidden">This is TR1_TD3</td>
    <td>This is TR1_TD4</td>
    <td>This is TR1_TD5</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>This is TR2-TD1</td>
    <td class="hidden">This is TR2-TD2</td>
    <td class="hidden">This is TR2-TD3</td>
    <td class="cant">Can't with Pure Css</td>
    <td class="hidden">This is TR2-TD5</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

If I get you correctly I'd say this is not achievable using pure CSS if your markup is dynamic at browser execution time with javascript.

If you have control over its generation process and your markup is dynamic at server execution time (PHP, Java, whatever...), you can add two more classes, .first-visible and .last-visible to the appropiate elements and style them in CSS.

CSS4 adds the necessary features to achieve this but its support it's still undefined: https://css4-selectors.com/selector/css4/structural-pseudo-class/

Are you able to add plain javascript instead of jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Im not completly sure if this is waht you are asking for but, here is my solution of how I would handle it:

When the document is loaded use jQuery to add a class to all the elements you want to handle.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("elements to select").addClass("selected"); // to all the elements you 
     want to handle
});
```

Then in the css just use that class to edit the selected elements

```
.selected{
 // your code
}
```

Comment: need without jquery

Answer (score 0):

> This Stuff will work for you and i hope you will be glad to see it.
>   You can see only First TD and Last TD is visible else are hidden.

```css
table{
  border :1px solid #ddd;
}
//tr td{
//  display: none; // For Hide other TD
//}

tr td:first-child{
  color: darkgreen;
  display:block;
  background:lightgreen;
  padding:7px 15px;
  border-right:2px solid red;
}

tr td:last-child{
  color: skyblue;
  display:block;
  padding:7px 15px;
  background:blue;
  border-right:2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
   <td>This is first-child</td>
   <td>This is 2</td>
   <td>This is 3</td>
   <td>This is last-child</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>one</td>
   <td>Two</td>
   <td>Three</td>
   <td>Four</td>
   <td>Five</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you understood the problem wrongly. if i hide the last column, whatever is visible now in that last column style should get applied. (Hide columns in the grid, always apply some style to last column)

Comment: what exactly you want to do with first and last column?

Comment: Now you can see your first and last td  border has been red.

Comment: see my example  given above. and result also.

Comment: You said that , You want to set up right border red on first and last td on your row that why its should be like that. if you want something else, give description with image with highlight what you want as done.